# Detect and block spam on Linux VPN network

Tags: sendmail, iptables, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

I'm the admin of a VPN server. One of the users is sending spam from his system through our VPN server, but I can't see which user is so I have blocked port 25 by firewall and sendmail by `chmod`ing it, but I got several abuse reports again.

How can I block spam from being sent on our network? I have no idea, only I know their system is infected by malware.

*For example*:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -tcp header email 3/min -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you sure that you block SMTP for all OUTPUT chain traffic?
I'd suggest you to block TCP:465 & TCP:587 too by the way:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 465 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 587 -j DROP
```

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html) for more examples about iptables config.

Comment: i`m not begginer, actually once users connected they can send spam as they want, emails transfered suing my ip